# Solr is not concatenating words in a query

Tags: solr, cpu-word, concatenation

I am having trouble with Solr.  I want it to concatenate words in the search query.  For example, I want to be able to search "data link" and have it hit on a document that contains "datalink" (Google does this -- so why is this so difficult with Solr?).

Here are the index and query analyzer settings from schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="0" 
            catenateNumbers="0" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" 
            synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
            ignoreCase="true" 
            expand="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="0" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This is the output of debugQuery when I search "data link":

```
"rawquerystring": "\"data link\"\n",
"querystring": "\"data link\"\n",
"parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(text:\"data link\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "text:\"data link\"",
```

This is the output of debugQuery when I search "data-link" -- this also does not hit on "datalink", even though it seems to be there in the MultiPhraseQuery?  Can someone explain?

```
"rawquerystring": "\"data-link\"\n",
"querystring": "\"data-link\"\n",
"parsedquery": "MultiPhraseQuery(text:\"(data datalink) link\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "text:\"(data datalink) link\"",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very complex ground, but most of what's going on here seems to be due to the WordDelimiterFilter, and its arguments `generateWordParts` and `concatentateWords`. In the indexing you are generating parts, but not concatenating, but in the querying you are doing both.

**When Indexing**

1. "**Data Link**": This was going to be indexed as two separate words, regardless. The `WordDelimiterFilter` doesn't second-guess what are already two separate words.
2. "**Data-Link**": This is ambiguous, and could be one word or two. Because your indexing analysis specifies `generateWordParts`, this is indexed as "data link".

**When Searching**

1. "**Data Link**"": This is two separate words, and like at index time, the query-time `WordDelimiterFilter` doesn't change this. It's still two words.
2. "**Data-Link**": The search analysis is configured differently than the index analysis, so this is searched both as "data link" and as "datalink".

**The upshot?**

Your search for "data-link" does search for the term "datalink", but the values you are indexing are only going to be indexed as "datalink" if they are written that way in the first place, because you never activate `concatenateWords` when indexing.

One thing you may choose to do is to select either `concatenateWords` *or* `generateWordParts`, and activate one or the other for the field, both when indexing and when searching. Another option I have chosen is to use a `<copyField/>` in the `schema.xml` to copy the value between a field in which word parts are generated and one in which words are concatenated. At the least, I have found that trying to do both concatenation and parts in a single field plays havoc with phrase searching as the position numbers of individual terms get out of whack when the terms can't be clearly counted.

But, if your hope is to have a document where the word **datalink** can be found when searching for **data link**, then the `WordDelimiterFilter` won't help, as it will never consider **datalink** to be a candidate for being two words, or **data link** as a candidate for being one word. Its specialty lies in ambiguous circumstances caused by things like hyphens and apostrophes.

Instead, you may need to construct your own logical query. (Logical operators work in the Standard/Lucene Query Handler, and the Extended-Dismax Query Handler, but not the Dismax Query Handler.) This kind of query can get complicated quickly, but something like `(+data +link) OR datalink` is a good first step. If three terms are included, it gets hard to know which might potentially be concatenated, so a query like `datalinkcisco OR (+datalink +cisco) OR (+data +linkcisco) OR (+data +link +cisco)` might start to come into play. (And imagine it with four terms!)

This gets very complicated, very quickly, and if there are only a few cases of terms that may be concatenated only some of the time, you might try a `SynonymFilter` instead. This allows a synonym file to be established with rules like:

```
data link => datalink
```

So that all instances of "data link" will be indexed or queried (as configured) as "datalink" instead. This can normalize the specific search terms without opening the can of worms where we don't trust the user to know where spaces belong at all.

`SynonymFilter`s can be good for other things. For example, if you filter punctuation out of your search index, "C++" and "C" may end up appearing equivalent to Solr. With a synonym rule of:

```
C++ => cplusplus
```

this ends up completely distinct. (Sure, no real person would ever search for cplusplus, but if you apply the same conversion to "C++" in your indexed documents *and* in your users' queries, then they never have to know that "cplusplus" is the value that actually made the match.)

Comment: "Your search for "data-link" does search for the term "datalink"" -- actually, it doesn't hit on "datalink".  Try it yourself.  I think the problem is that this multiphrase query it generates `"parsedquery": "MultiPhraseQuery(text:\"(data datalink) link\")"` is not what it should be generating.  When I search for "data-link" it only hits on "data link" and not on "datalink"

Comment: Yes, I could have been more explicit. The search _does_ contain "datalink". Whether it actually returns a result containing that term is a different question, and can depend on other factors in your query configuration. That probably sounds like a dodge, but it is true. And, you truly didn't include enough information about your query configuration for me to know for sure.

This query should work if you loosen your matching criteria, not that I would necessarily recommend it. You could make your search an "OR" search with `q.op=OR` (standard query parser), or `mm=1` (dismax/edismax).

Comment: In general, applying both `concatenateWords` and `generateWordParts` in your query analyzer is probably a bad idea. It's a lot more common to use both together in an index analyzer if both are needed, though I've found that this can be dangerous with phrase searches as well. For clean, flexible phrase searching on terms that may or may not be hyphenated, the best model I've found is the one I outlined above that uses the `copyField`.

Comment: You may also want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492868

Comment: Can you explain the copyField solution in more detail?  How do I make a query to both fields at the same time, with one query analyzer generating word parts and the other concatenating the text?

Comment: To create the two different fields with different analyzers, you need two different `fieldType` blocks. The one you have is called `text_en_splitting`, so the other might be `text_en_combining`. You create two fields, using a different `fieldType` for each, and then the `<copyField source="field1" dest="field2"/>` entry in the schema.xml makes sure that data you insert into `field1` ends up in both.

Comment: To search them together, it depends which query parser you're using, though it's easiest if you're using [dismax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) or extended dismax. With these parsers you can supply a `qf` argument that lists the fields you want to search, e.g. `qf=field1 field2` and then your main query doesn't specify a field, e.g. `q="data-link"`. The parser breaks down the query and applies it to each field in the `qf`.

Comment: If you prefer to use the [standard query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser), you need to provide the detailed breakdown yourself, so something like: `q=field1:"data-link" OR field2:"data-link".

Comment: And do I only need to set `stored="true"` for field1?  I'm doing hit highlighting, so I want to make sure that that works for both fields.

Comment: Oh, but when you said "It's a lot more common to use both together in an index analyzer if both are needed, though I've found that this can be dangerous with phrase searches as well." -- do you mean that if I don't want to mangle my phrase searches, the two separate fields I'm using should each individually use `stored="true"`?  That would double the size of my index though, wouldn't it?  BTW, this is all starting to sound like a real shortcoming of Solr -- I can't believe this search engine doesn't have a better way to search phrases that may or may not appear with concatenated words in text

Comment: I suppose if you are doing hit highlighting you would need both fields to be stored. You _could_ have these two fields indexed and have a third display field that's stored. You would have to use regex to apply your own highlighting, which might make things tricky with things like stemming... probably not worth it. In the end it's a choice you have to make. For the largest index I currently manage (by storage size, not record count), I have all of the text fields indexed four times in different fields.

Comment: The other way to go is to pick a single method for indexing that gets as close as you can manage to the behavior you want. You could index with both `generateWordParts` and `concatenateWords`, but search with only one or the other. The StackOverflow issue I linked to above goes into _how_ this can confuse searching. The idea being that it's hard to tell whether a word is the 2nd or 3rd word in a phrase if the previous term could be one or two words. This is a downside that only affects searches that involve both phrase searching and records with hyphenated terms, so it may not be too frequent.

Answer (score 0):

To allow `data link` and `datalink` to match you have to add the `ShingleFilter` to your indexer and query chain:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter

You can combine this with the `WordDelimiterFilter`.

To reduce the amount of generated but probably useless tokens you can add a `LengthFilter` with `min=2` and some reasonable max value. For example, WDF could produce from "iPhone6s": "i", "Phone", "6", "s" (and more depending on the config).

Also, the `RemoveDuplicateTokensFilter` can be added last in that chain:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter